# Javascript: How to get the source of the VM file?

Tags: javascript, reverse

I can see from the stack that this file looks like it was picked up by the eval function.

[image: Chrome VM Stack]

**when I open the second file, I can find "send" function, and I switch line 4409. So can I be sure that the source of the VM file was obtained by requesting the server?**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When using `eval()`, the javascript gets thrown into the **Chrome Debugger** VMs. To view js created with `eval()` with *Chrome Debugger Sources*, set this attribute at the end of js:

```
//@ sourceURL=dynamicScript.js
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it could work.But javascript code sent by server, I can't set attribute at the end of js !!